# Is there an elegant way to divide an HTML table cell into a grid of 9 (Bootstrap)

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I want to embed several "directional" icons (arrows) into an up/down/left/right grid on a per row table to allow users to edit hierarchical data structures directly.

It seems either I have to use `colspan=3` and `rowspan=3` on all the other elements OR I have to do the table within a table route.

Is there another way?

Does Bootstrap have any supporting CSS to do this with `span`'s and/or `div`'s ?

I am building a generic solution that I can reuse as needed.

think like this:

`x | U | x 
 L | x | R
 x | D | x`

except that the U, L, R and D are Font Awesome arrow icons indicating Up, Left, Right and Down respectively.

`x | /\ | x 
 <-| x. |->
 x | \/ | x`

Just ignore the x's...

Comment: Can you provide a jsfiddle or jsbin of your current html?  It is hard to understand exactly what you need without seeing what you currently have.

Comment: @photo_tom I've added ASCII art to help confuse (ah clarify) things...

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried with   CSS3

[CSS3 Multiple Columns](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_multiple_columns.asp)

Comment: That is explicitly for text that flows between columns. Interesting but not applicable here because if squished any reflow would look horrible.